Why is my Google social login working despite my app not being published?
I have implemented Google social login for my web application. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Created an OAuth 2.0 Client ID in the Google Cloud Console.

Added my application's domains under "Authorized JavaScript origins".

Added the necessary redirect URIs under "Authorized redirect URIs".


However, I have not published my Google app yet it is in testing. Despite this, the Google social login is working for all users.
I expected that the login functionality might be restricted or limited because the app is not published, but everything seems to work fine.
My questions are:

Is it normal for Google social login to work even if the app is not published?

What are the implications of not publishing the app? Are there any potential issues I should be aware of?

Is there any additional step I need to take to ensure the app works smoothly in production once it is published?


Here are some additional details about my setup:

I have configured the OAuth 2.0 Client ID correctly.

All necessary origins and redirect URIs are specified in the Google Cloud Console.

The login flow redirects users to Google's login page, and after successful authentication, they are redirected back to my application with an authorization code.


Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
